# How to interact with python scripts on geany after running, just like on IDLE

Tags: python, ide, geany

On IDLE after running a script/program made with python by pressing f5, you could still interact with the program even after it finished running.

[image]

But on Geany, when running it, and when the program finishes, it just asks to

"Press return to Continue"

[image]

I spent a while trying to finding a way to do that on Geany as well but came up with no luck, so I was wondering if there were any ways that add the functionality of interacting with the program after it runs on Geany?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, after some researching and some more tinkering, I have discovered a few things.

1) The proper term for it, is probably called the interactive python console

2) No need for plugins, first open a python file with geany, then just go to Build > Set Build Commands and then on the Execute commands way at the bottom, add "-i" without the quotes right after python. So it should show something like python -i "%f"